# xcode - switch between more than 2 view controllers

Tags: xcode, controller, switch-statement

I have several .xib files (page1, page2 ...) and want to switch between them using buttons (as a navigation bar)

I am using

```
page1 *second = [[page1 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:second animated: YES]; 


page2 *second = [[page2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:second animated: YES];
```

and so on...

I learned that this consumes a lot of memory because I am presenting a view over and over again and after switching back and forth the app sometimes crashes. 
So, question is what can I do?

I tried this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

but after dismiss it returns to the previous page and I can not navigate to another one.

Probably I used a stupid approach, however, I've done a few apps that way and don't want to change the controller completely.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is going on between your views? are they always identical or do you have them generate new content each time? What kind of memory usage are you seeing in Instrument?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create `IBActions` from that 2 blocks of code an link that `IBActions` to the right button.